# How do I replicate %Dictionary.ClassDefintionQuery's Summary() in SQL?

Tags: intersystems-cache

There is a procedure in `%Dictionary.ClassDefinitionQuery` which lists a class summary; in Java I call it like this:

```
public void readClasses(final Path dir)
    throws SQLException
{
    final String call
        = "{ call %Dictionary.ClassDefinitionQuery_Summary() }";

    try (
        final CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(call);
        final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    ) {
        String className;
        int count = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            // Skip if System is not 0
            if (rs.getInt(5) != 0)
                continue;

            className = rs.getString(1);

            // Also skip if the name starts with a %
            if (className.charAt(0) == '%')
                continue;

            //System.out.println(className);
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("read: " + count);
    }
}
```

In namespace SAMPLES this returns 491 rows.

I try and replicate it with a pure SQL query like this:

```
private void listClasses(final Path dir)
    throws SQLException
{
    final String query = "select id, super"
        + " from %Dictionary.ClassDefinition"
        + " where System = '0' and name not like '\\%%' escape '\\'";

    try (
        final PreparedStatement statement
            = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    ) {
        int count = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + ';' + rs.getString(2));
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("list: " + count);
    }
}
```

Yet when running the program I get this:

```
list: 555
read: 491
```

Why are the results different?

I have looked at the code of `%Dictionary.ClassDefinitionQuery` but I don't understand why it gives different results... All I know, if I store the names in sets and compare, is that:

- nothing is missing from list that is in read;
- most, but not all, classes returned by list which are not in read are CSP pages.

But that's it.

How I can I replicate the behaviour of the summary procedure in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different is in one property. %Dictionary.ClassDefinitionQuery_Summary shows only classes with Deployed<>2. So, sql must be such.

```
select id,super from %Dictionary.ClassDefinition where deployed <> 2
```

But one more things is, why count may be different is, such sql requests may be compilled to temporary class, for example "%sqlcq.SAMPLES.cls22"

Comment: Hmm, and what does that `deployed` column tell us? Also, I don't select classes which names start with '%', so I won't get any %sqlcq. I'm really too much of a rookie, despite having a full install and therefore all documentation at hand :(

Comment: Aaand... Spot on. That was exactly it! You are going to become my Intersystems hero :p

Comment: In Cache classes, may be without any source codes, so, this flag shows it as it tells in documentation "Indicates whether the class has been deployed, that is, disassociated from the source that was used to build it."

Comment: Hmm, in `%Dictionary.ClassDefinitionQuery`, method `SummaryFetchRows`, line 75, I see `If $listget(data,16)=2 Set no=no-1 Continue` <-- is that it? I don't see that `data` defined anywhere... (well, afterwards I'll have yet another question, heh)

Comment: Yes, it is, and thats how I found Deployed property. But why it so, it is not so easy to explain for rookies

Comment: Well, from showing the table structure, I at least know that this is not the column number (it shows as number 11 in the management portal); I also know that this can't be either of a property of parameter since the class is abstract and only contains class methods... But that's about it.

Comment: please give some more examples, may be screenshots in new question or anything else

Comment: What do you mean by "examples"? Also, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29917676/1093528) is my latest problem ;)

Comment: I mean where you see it as number 11 ?

Comment: In the management portal, System explorer, namespace '%SYS', select `%Dictionary.ClassDefinition` in `Tables` on the left side, on the right side select `Catalog details`, then `Fields` under it

Comment: Well, I see, yes a number 11, but it is just a number of column and it is not  matter in most cases. So, 16, it is position for Deployed in structure which saved in global ^rINDEXCLASS.