# What privileges are needed to run this query?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I use InterSystem's cache JDBC driver to query the "database dictionary" in order to retrieve source code from classes.

I have this SQL query:

```
final String query = "select id, super"
    + " from %Dictionary.ClassDefinition"
    + " where System = '0'"
    + " and name not like '\\%%' escape '\\'"
    + " and deployed != 2";
```

Right now, the user performing this query has `%All` as a role, which is of course not a good thing. I try and reduce the privileges of this user to the strict minimum necessary.

I am connected to namespace SAMPLES; I have created a role, say `FOO` to which I have given these privileges:

- `%Service_SQL` (U);
- `%DB_SAMPLES` (R);
- `select` privilege on table `%Dictionary.ClassDefinition` in namespace `%SYS`.

I have tried and given my user only this role; but it fails at execution (-99 error translated: "privilege violation"):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [SQLCODE: <-99>:<Violación de privilegio >]
[Location: <Prepare>]
[%msg: <User sonar is not privileged for the operation>]
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.getServerError(CacheConnection.java:1312)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.processError(CacheConnection.java:1552)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.InStream.readHeader(InStream.java:164)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CachePreparedStatement.prepareInternal(CachePreparedStatement.java:633)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CachePreparedStatement.prepare(CachePreparedStatement.java:594)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CachePreparedStatement.<init>(CachePreparedStatement.java:141)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.prepareStatement(CacheConnection.java:1860)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.prepareStatement(CacheConnection.java:484)
    at es.litesolutions.cacheqc.dbread.CacheDbReader.listClasses(CacheDbReader.java:47)
    at es.litesolutions.cacheqc.dbread.CacheDbReader.main(CacheDbReader.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

What privileges are missing so that I can use `PreparedStatement`s?

(Yes, I know the query above has no bind variables but other queries will have bind variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you should add access for concrete table. It is possibble to do for role or for user, in tab SQL tables. Just add table %Dictiinary.Classdefinition

To find errors in settings of permissions, you can also use [Audit](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20151/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_audit)

You should add access for table `%Dictionary.ClassDefinition` from namespace SAMPLES. It is important to choose correct namespace, because you connect to `SAMPLES`.
[image]

Comment: I did that but it still fails with the same error :( How can I debug it and provide reliable info?

Comment: Audit can help to find erros in permissions.  
http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20151/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_audit

Comment: I enabled it, by refreshing the page I do see messages for each query but not the reason why it failed :( I hate being so ignorant...

Comment: First, can you see the edited question? I have forgotten to mention that I gave select access to this particular table to the user. Also, how much information would you need from the user profile?

Comment: Yes, I see, and while your user connect to SAMPLES namespace, you have to add access to the same namespace as well, for system classes too. So, try to add access to this class in namespace SAMPLES.

Comment: Audit may be not so usefull, but you can collect information about login and check which roles got particular user, or loginfailures to see cause of that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the user logs in just fine. I did enable auditing, but in the auditing message I could not find anything about why this particular operaton failed :(

Comment: In audit you can set some system audit events, such as Login, LoginFailure, Protect. Did you change access to class from namespace %SYS to SAMPLES, as I offer earlier ?

Comment: OK, I have somewhat misread. "try to add access to xxx in namespace SAMPLES" <-- how do I do that?

Comment: As you already done it, `select` privelege on that table in namespace `%SYS`, just do it again but in first select namespace `SAMPLES`. Tab `SQL Tables` when editing role

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I updated, my answer with screenshot, hope it will help.